# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()

Tags: plugins, multisite

I have some strange error or may be I do not have the skills to tackle this issue.
I am building a plugin for Multisite. When is use `is_admin()`, my plugin works fine but when I use `is_super_admin` it shows me this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user()`. I did my search but could not be able to find any solution.

My Code is this

```
if(!is_super_admin()){
    add_action('widgets_init','my_unregister_widdget');
    function my_unregister_widgets() {
        unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Pages' );
        unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Calendar' );
    }
}
```

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996433/is-super-admin-call-produces-fatal-error-in-wordpress)  but it's not helping me.

Comment: Just a note: `is_admin()` checks if you are in back or front end, **it has nothing to do with the user being "admin"**. Opposed to `is_super_admin()`, which indeed checks for the user role. Also, please [don't Multi-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/185667) the same Question in different Stack sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`wp_get_current_user()` is a pluggable function and not yet available when your plugin is *included*. You have to wait for the action `plugins_loaded`:

Example:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wpse_92517_init' );

function wpse_92517_init()
{
    if(!is_super_admin())
        add_action('widgets_init','my_unregister_widget');
}

function my_unregister_widgets() {
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Pages' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Calendar' );
}
```

Or move the check into the widget function:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_unregister_widget' );

function my_unregister_widgets() 
{
    if ( is_super_admin() )
        return;

    // not super admin
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Pages' );
    unregister_widget( 'WP_Widget_Calendar' );
}
```